# UML Model traversal in Python

Tags: python, uml

I want to traverse a model in Python. The model can be very big with lot of branches,
child nodes, classes and attributes.

Are there any specific algorithm for UML model traversal in Python?

Comment: I suppose any graph traversal algorithm should work. I don't think there's anything that sets UML apart in that regard.

Comment: Do you have some Samples or links @vipw